# java -version doesn't write to stdout?

Tags: macos, java, stdout

Either I'm doing something silly or Sun is. How come something like:

```
java -version > version.txt
```

Still prints out to stdout and leaves version.txt empty? I'm checking out the exit code, and it's still 0, so is not that's writing to stderr.

I need this because I'm building a test-environment tool and want to check if the version of Java is adequate, I was planning to catch that version output, but now I'm stuck.

I'm on OS X Leopard, Java version 1.6.0_20.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
java -version &> version.txt
```

The exit code has nothing to do with where it outputs.

Comment: Could you please explain the `&` or at least say what it's called? It's really hard to search for in Google.

Comment: Nice one, it works. Care to explain the difference between what I was doing and adding &? Thanks : )

Comment: `>` on its own only redirects stdout. `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr in most shells.

Comment: Thanks, there is also this `2>&1`. Is that the same as  `&` in most cases?

Comment: @Yar: As far as I know, the 2>&1 form is for Windows.

Comment: @Ash: **`2>&1` is the same in POSIX-compatible shells** (`bash`, `zsh`, `ash`). The syntax is `x>&y` where `x` and `y` are file descriptors (`1` for stdout, `2` for stderr). Only `>&` and `&>` are `bash`-specific extensions (which both mean `1>somefile 2>&1`)

Comment: @gawity, thanks for that. So you're saying that Ignacio's answer will only work on Bash?

Comment: @Yar, `&>` is a non-standard extension. Both *bash* and *zsh* know it though. Bare `>&` (no numbers) is also non-standard, but also both *bash* and *zsh* know it. All Bourne-like shells (including POSIX conforming shells) know `x>&y`.

Comment: Redirections such as `[fd]>file`, `[fd]>>file`, `[fd]<file` and `[fd]>&fd` work in both POSIX-compatible shells **and** `cmd.exe`. Thus **`>somefile 2>&1` will always work**. On the other hand, bare `>& somefile` is a bashism. _(Adding to my previous comment)_

Answer (score 9):

It's kind of a feature nowadays. ;-)

From [an ancient bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4380614):

> We should think very, very carefully before ever fixing this bug.  It's
> obviously the wrong thing to print version information to stderr, but since
> we've been doing that since the beginning of time it seems likely that we'll
> break existing systems built on top of Java if we change it now.  If we do
> decide to change this then it must wait until the Tiger release so that
> adequate testing can be done.

Comment: HA! What about that : ) Thank for the link to the bug, kind of makes me feel better.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to Ignacio's answer:

Parsing the output of `java -version` is rather complex and error-prone (and the output is not guaranteed to always have the same format, especially with non-Sun JVMs).

To check the java version, you could run a small java program that checks the appropriate system properties: see Javadocs for [getProperties()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29). This is the official, documented way to get information about the Java environment. You probably want to check:

- java.version (exact version number of Java installation, e.g. 1.6.0_15 )
- java.specification.version (the Java platform version, e.g. 1.5 or 1.6)